# How to create react tabs with fragment identifiers (hash links)?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-tabs

I use react-tabs (https://reactcommunity.org/react-tabs/) to create 4 tabs. Now I need to create routes like this "https://example.com/page=01#tab1", "https://example.com/page=01#tab2" for them. They open page with choosen tab when you click on tab name.

I tried to replace react-tabs with few `<Link to="#tab1>Tab1</Link>` and `<Route path='#tab1' render={() => <MyComponent store={store}/>}/>` from react-router-dom, but tabs aren't switched.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found only one solution: I use window.location.hash to set and get hashlink value. Also I add callback onMouseDown to tab names to imitate router: I change window.location.href in this callback.